# Simple binary search tree in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

Here there is code for a simple `BST` in Java that keys are only `int`, but when I want to test it and use `print()` just `root.key` can be printed and `root.right` and `root.left` are `null`.

```
public class BST {

    private class Node {
        private int key;
        private Node left, right;

        public Node(int key) {
            this.key = key;
        }
    }

    private Node root;

    public BST(int key) {
        root = new Node(key);
    }

    public void insert(int key) {
        insert(root, key);
    }

    private void insert(Node x, int key) {
        if (x == null) {
            x = new Node(key);
        }
        if (key > x.key) {
            insert(x.right, key);
        } else if (key < x.key) {
            insert(x.left, key);
        } else {
            x.key = key;
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        print(root);
    }

    private void print(Node x) {
        System.out.print(x.key + " ");
        if (x.left != null)
            print(x.left);
        if (x.right != null)
            print(x.right);
    }
}
```

For example, when I insert 25, 9, 10, 30, 40 and call `print()` then it just prints 25.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x = new Node(key);
```

This assignment basically throws away the `new Node`, because `x` is just a local variable. You are *not* modifying the callers reference here, you are just modifying the local copy of the reference the caller gave you. What you could do is `return` the `x` and have the caller assign it:

```
x = insert(x, 3);
```

The `insert` would then look something like this:

```
private Node insert(Node x, int key) {
    if (x==null){
        return new Node(key);
    }
    if (key > x.key) {
        x.right = insert(x.right, key);
    }else if (key < x.key) {
        x.left = insert(x.left, key);
    }else{
        x.key = key;
    }
    return x;
}
```